# How to index XML elements in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am dummy to PHP and XML, so please be patient if my question seems dumb.

I want to know how to index the XML elements so that I can access them. I am planning to put them into an array. However, I don't know how to get the number of elements returned.

Here are the codes:

**`exer.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<actionstars>
 <name>Jean Claude Van Damme</name>
 <name>Scott Adkins</name>
 <name>Michael Jai White</name>
 <name>Dolph Lundgren</name>
 <name>Tom Cruise</name>
 <name>Michael Worth</name>
</actionstars>
```

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
 $dom = new DomDocument();
 $dom->load("exer.xml");
 $names = $dom->getElementsByTagName("name");
 echo count($names);
 foreach($names as $name) {
     print $name->textContent . "<br />";
 }
?>
```

When I do the `echo count($names);` it returns `1`, which is obviously not the number of elements. Please help.

Comment: Does it output the nodes in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the return value of `getElementsByTagName`, which will be a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

Also for your problem you could do something like:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("name") as $nameNode) {
  $names[] = $nameNode->nodeValue;
}
```

You don't have to actually check the return value of `getElementsByTagName`, for it will allways be a DOMNodeList. This way you can use it directly in the foreach-loop whithout assigning unneeded variables.

What you have to check, is the size of `$names`, after the loop.