# How to get an xml element by index

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file that contains a list of elements. I want to retrieve a specific element by index. I looked around for a while and didn't find anything that worked for me.

I would have thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
echo($xml->children()[0]);
```

I'm not very experienced in php, coming from a C# background, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: And then they invented Google...

Comment: I googled a ton, and couldn't find anything that worked

Comment: 4th search result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173646/how-to-index-xml-elements-in-php

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit less hacky than that

Comment: `xpath` queries work.. in both `C#` & `PHP` :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array dereferencing was added in PHP 5.4 so your code will *(probably)* work with that version.

If you're stuck with an older version, simply try this

```
$children = $xml->children();
echo $children[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was doing it correctly. I think my school hasn't upgraded in a millenium